# QtDesigner in combination with PyQt (more specific adding a button to a tab created in QtDesigner

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm quite new to PyQt and QtDesigner so probably it's easy what I'm tring to do but I couldn't find a working example anywhere.

I've created a GUI in QtDesigner with a tabWidget and multiple tabs (which are QWidgets) named tab,tab_2 etc.
Now I'm trying to add a pushbutton for example to the first tab (called tab). My previous try created the button in a new window..
What is the correct way to do this?

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore, QtGui,uic
    from PyQt5.Qt import QPushButton

    class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.ui = uic.loadUi('example.ui',self)
        self.ui.tab.btn1=QtWidgets.QPushButton('buttonn')
        self.ui.tab.btn1.show()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication 
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window=Main()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The normal way to use QTabWidget is to do the following: Create a
>   QTabWidget. Create a QWidget for each of the pages in the tab dialog,
>   but do not specify parent widgets for them. Insert child widgets into
>   the page widget, using layouts to position them as normal. Call
>   addTab() or insertTab() to put the page widgets into the tab widget,
>   giving each tab a suitable label with an optional keyboard shortcut.

Try this:

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('example.ui',self)

        btn1=QtWidgets.QPushButton('buttonn')
        self.ui.tabwidget.addTab(btn1, 'Tab name')
```

If you have the tabs already created, just create the button as a child of the widget inside the tab:

```
        btn1=QtWidgets.QPushButton('buttonn', self.ui.tab)
```